# TestNg test not running with maven build

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have `TestNg` unit tests which is supposed to run with my `maven clean install`.

I don't have any `test-suite.xml`s in my pom to run testes. Expectation is to run all my test files without any configuration with the maven build.

But this is not happening.

My test class goes like this

```
public class CreateUtilty{

  @Test
  public void testScope(){
    Creationutiltiy.create("myApp");
    // remaing code
   }

}
```

What could have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running testNG as you are with no configuration, the surefire plugin expects your test classes to end with Test. Try changing your test class name to `CreateUtilityTest`  and it should be picked up.

The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) for the maven surefile plugin contains useful information to help you get started.

To find out more about how to include/exlude tests based on naming convention read [this](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire-archives/surefire-2.21.0/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: Nope, it's how the surefire plugin works. You can read about how to configure it in the second link I've now included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try execute your class with following syntax

mvn -Dtest=CreateUtilty test